# In Pandas, how do I find every 3rd row for each key in one column and add a new column with the 3rd row's info?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Input:

| user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:46:26 |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:47:27 |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:48:27 |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:49:27 |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:50:27 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:29:34 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:30:34 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:31:34 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:32:33 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:33:33 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:34:33 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:44:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:45:30 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:46:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:47:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:48:28 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:49:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:50:29 |

Expected Output:

| user_id | timestamp | timestamp2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:46:26 | 2021-01-17 14:48:27 |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:48:27 | 2021-01-17 14:50:27 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:29:34 | 2021-02-03 19:31:34 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:31:34 | 2021-02-03 19:33:33 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:33:33 | 2021-02-03 19:34:33 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:44:29 | 2021-02-04 16:46:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:46:29 | 2021-02-04 16:48:28 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:48:28 | 2021-02-04 16:50:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:50:29 | 2021-02-04 16:50:29 |

Like B and C, if there is not enough 3rd row left, it's ok to pick the closest one and put the timestamp into the new column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. calc, `cumcount() // 3` for every 3 rows in *user_id*
2. then it's a simple `groupby()` with `first` and `last`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""user_id timestamp
A   2021-01-17 14:46:26
A   2021-01-17 14:47:27
A   2021-01-17 14:48:27
A   2021-01-17 14:49:27
A   2021-01-17 14:50:27
B   2021-02-03 19:29:34
B   2021-02-03 19:30:34
B   2021-02-03 19:31:34
B   2021-02-03 19:32:33
B   2021-02-03 19:33:33
B   2021-02-03 19:34:33
C   2021-02-04 16:44:29
C   2021-02-04 16:45:30
C   2021-02-04 16:46:29
C   2021-02-04 16:47:29
C   2021-02-04 16:48:28
C   2021-02-04 16:49:29
C   2021-02-04 16:50:29"""), sep="\t")

df.timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df2 = (df.assign(grp=df.groupby("user_id")["user_id"].cumcount()//3)
 .groupby(["user_id","grp"])["timestamp"].agg(timestamp="first",timestamp2="last")
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns="grp")
)
```

| user_id | timestamp | timestamp2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:46:26 | 2021-01-17 14:48:27 |
| A | 2021-01-17 14:49:27 | 2021-01-17 14:50:27 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:29:34 | 2021-02-03 19:31:34 |
| B | 2021-02-03 19:32:33 | 2021-02-03 19:34:33 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:44:29 | 2021-02-04 16:46:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:47:29 | 2021-02-04 16:49:29 |
| C | 2021-02-04 16:50:29 | 2021-02-04 16:50:29 |

Comment: Hm I got this error running your code: TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'

Comment: pandas version?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: requires pandas >= 0.25.0 , named aggregations